# MS SQL Server 2008 error on GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table I am trying to clean up so I just need the first address in the table for each `ClientId`

Table `Addresses` has these columns

```
Pk[Id]
[ClientId]
[AddressLine1]
[AddressLine2]
```

Query I use:

```
SELECT *
FROM Addresses
ORDER BY ClientId
```

result =

```
1   1   foo     bar
2   1   foo2    bar2
3   1   foo3    bar3
4   1   foo4    bar4
5   2   foo     bar2
95  2   foo     bar5
97  2   foo     bar6
8   3   foo2    bar7
```

wanted result =

```
1   1   foo     bar   <--is first match for clientid = 1
5   2   foo     bar2  <-- is first match for clientid = 2
8   3   foo2    bar7  <-- is first match for clientid = 3
```

This need to work for n clientids

I tried

```
SELECT *
FROM Addresses
GROUP BY ClientId
```

The resulting error is (Column 'Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server requires that when using a GROUP BY you need to either use an aggregate function on the columns in the select list or add them to the GROUP BY.

Your original query could be changed to use the following:

```
select a.id, a.clientid, a.address1, a.address2
from addresses a
inner join
(
    select clientid, MIN(id) id
    from addresses
    group by clientid
) d
    on a.clientid = d.clientid
    and a.id = d.id;
```

As you can see this uses a subquery that returns the `min(id)` for each `clientId`, this only groups by the `clientid`. You then join this to your table to return only those rows with the min id for each client.

Comment: This Worked Flawlessly! Thank you for your speedy response

Comment: An approach using ROW_NUMBER will perform better by avoiding a JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting multiple lines because you're selecting a field you don't want to be grouping by.  If you just want the first entry for each clientID you can use an analytic function like ROW_NUMBER
Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY clientid ORDER BY ID) as RowRank
      FROM Addresses)sub
WHERE RowRank = 1
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientId ORDER BY ID) as RowRank FROM Addresses)WHERE RowRank = 1  gives the error Invalid Column name 'RowRank' at the where clause

Comment: Subquery was missing alias, see answer.

Answer (score 1):

You did SELECT *. Every field in the select list must either be in the GROUP BY clause or inside an agregation function (MAX, MIN, SUM, AVG, etc.).

This explains the error. For the SQL that solves your problem see Goat_CO answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the  Single-Value Rule: all columns in the select-list must be explicitly part of the GROUP BY criteria, or else inside an aggregate function, e.g. COUNT(), MAX(), etc.